# Are there java web application templates similar to appfuse?

Tags: java

I guess I am looking for hints and info about something that it is 'bigger' than a web app framework like JSF and the like.  Sort of like Rails for Java web apps... or I could be completely off-base.

Comment: What functionality are you looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for but if is a "Rails for Java web apps" the closest thing is [Grails](http://www.grails.org). Furthermore there is [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo) (also from SpringSource, as is Grails) and [Seam](http://seamframework.org).

What these frameworks have in common is that they provide a **complete stack** for building Java based web applications together with **productivity tooling** (and a productivity *language* in the case of Grails as most Groovy developers would say).

Major differences are:

- *Grails*: Spring stack  + Groovy language + productivity shell
- *Roo*: Spring stack + plain Java + productivity shell
- *Seam*: Java EE stack (EJB3, JSF, etc) + plain Java + productivity shell

Answer (score 0):

The best Java web framework I know is wicket. http://wicket.apache.org
There are a lot of extensions but best thing is the great separation of java-code and html.

Comment: it looks like wicket could be part of a larger application template... It looks like Appfuse creates applications that leverage Wicket.

Comment: Wicket is no more an application template than any other web framework.

Answer (score 0):

I did some more looking and ran into [JAG](http://jag.sourceforge.net/).  It appears to be an abandoned project.

I found it with this query: http://www.google.com/search?q=java+application+generator